# How to get common records from a same table against different ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table in my database shown below

```
 company_id | bill_month |
 134        |Apr
 134        |May
 134        |Jun
 134        |Jul
 134        |Aug2k19
 134        |Sep2k19
 391        |Aug2k19
 391        |Sep2k19
```

Now what i want is to fetch months common to all the companies,my desired result is show below

```
 bill_months|
 Aug2k19    |
 Sep2k19    |
```

I tried using self join with the following query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.bill_month FROM bf_monthly_bill AS a INNER JOIN bf_monthly_bill AS b 
 on a.bill_month=b.bill_month WHERE a.company_id IN('134','391')
```

Comment: All companies? Or specific companies?

Comment: specific, can b at least two or more than two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by bill_month and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT bill_month 
FROM bf_monthly_bill 
WHERE company_id IN ('134','391')
GROUP BY bill_month
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT company_id) = 2
```